# Text box not shown in GUI

Tags: python, tkinter

If you see these lines of code:

```
L1 = Label(root, text="Time Input")
L1.pack( side = LEFT)
E1 = Entry(root,bd = 5)
E1.pack
```

I have written a few line of codes for a text input but nothing was shown. I tried many ways but couldn't get it.

Here is my full code:

```
label = Label(root)
label.pack(side = RIGHT)

from Tkinter import *            
from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename      
root = Tk()
root.geometry("400x400")

f = Frame(root)
#f.pack_propagate(0) # don't shrink
f.pack()

bottomframe = Frame(root)
bottomframe.pack( side = BOTTOM )
scrollbar = Scrollbar(root)
scrollbar.pack( side = RIGHT, fill=Y )



def callback():
    r = open(askopenfilename(),'r')

def sel():
   selection = "You have selected " + str(v.get())
   label.config(text= selection)


a = Button( f,text='Choose File(Audio or Video)', fg="Blue",command=callback)
##b = Button(text='click me', command=callback)



a.pack(padx=10, pady=10, side=LEFT)
##b.pack()

##redbutton = Button(f, text="Red", fg="red")
##redbutton.pack( side = LEFT)
##
##greenbutton = Button(f, text="Brown", fg="brown")
##greenbutton.pack( side = LEFT )
##
##bluebutton = Button(f, text="Blue", fg="blue")
##bluebutton.pack( side = LEFT )
##
##blackbutton = Button(bottomframe, text="Black", fg="black")
##blackbutton.pack( side = BOTTOM)


v = StringVar()
R1 = Radiobutton(root, text="G", variable=v, value="G",
                  command=sel)
R1.pack( anchor = W )


R2 = Radiobutton(root, text="PG", variable=v, value="PG",
                  command=sel)
R2.pack( anchor = W )


R3 = Radiobutton(root, text="NC16", variable=v, value="NC16",
                  command=sel)
R3.pack( anchor = W )


R4 = Radiobutton(root, text="M18", variable=v, value="M18",
                  command=sel)
R4.pack( anchor = W )


R5 = Radiobutton(root, text="R21", variable=v, value="R21",
                  command=sel)
R5.pack( anchor = W )


L1 = Label(root, text="Time Input")
L1.pack( side = LEFT)
E1 = Entry(root,bd = 5)
E1.pack

label = Label(root)
label.pack(side = RIGHT)




R1.select()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to call the `pack` method of `E1` by placing `()` after it:

```
E1.pack()
```

Without this change, the entrybox will never be placed on the window.

Comment: thank you,i must be too tired from school today. i will accept the answer later because there seem to be an error with the button