# Why won't my text box show up in the GUI?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I'm trying to make a text box appear in a window using Tkinter, but it won't work... I've tried lots of things but nothing's working.

(No, I'm not going to look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24714873/text-box-not-shown-in-gui) which basically duplicates my situation. I already did, and it didn't help me at all.)

This is my current code:

```
# tkinter
from tkinter import *

# class
class App(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.pack()

        box = Text(width=90, height=50)
        self.pack()

# create the window
window = App()

# attributes
window.master.title("Text box")
window.master.minsize(800, 600)
window.master.maxsize(800, 600)

# start program
window.mainloop()
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to `pack` the box as well:

```
class App(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.pack()

        box = Text(width=90, height=50)
        box.pack()     #instead of self.pack()
```

Comment: I think it's bad practice to call `self.pack()`. Better to have the function that creates `App` pack (or grid or place) it.